# What's the best way to implement a mega menu in Orchard CMS?

Tags: html, css, orchardcms, megamenu, orchardcms-1.10

I am looking for some help in creating a mega menu in Orchard without editing any of the CSS files or applying any new themes.

Using the "Custom Code" widget (https://orchardtricks.dotnest.com/blog/custom-code-widget-orchard-cms), I am trying to implement a mega menu that works with the existing menu hierarchy in Orchard. Below would be an example of how the HTML gets built out:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu menu-mega-menu">
    <li class="first">
      <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Tools</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Microsoft Team Foundation Server</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Getting Access</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#">Training Material</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Add User Request</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Update User Request</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">TFS Reporting</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Accessing TFS Reports</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown last">
      <a href="#">Phases</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Conception and Approval &amp; Planning</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is what I managed to get going so far https://codepen.io/Zodem/pen/pmmyqM.

I'm looking to visually reproduce something similar to the mega menu at https://www.starbucks.ca/.

Comment: Hello MikeO. Please describe what is not working correctly and describe better at what point you need help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Maybe I didn’t ask the question properly but wouldn’t this be “a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development”? The CodePen I added is basically where I’m stuck and need further help.

Comment: There's nothing really specific to Orchard about creating a mega-menu. You should be able to change the navigation templates to get any HTML rendering you need, and then apply styles using CSS normally. The only real concern is that of performance, especially in Orchard 1, as rendering deep hierarchical structures can be heavy on the database, so you need to make sure you properly use the caching features of Orchard.